# Text not rendered in d3 visualization

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg, d3.js

I'm reviewing the code of the visualization here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045, and I'm curious to know why is **name** from the json file not rendered together with the nodes even though the code included:

```
node.append("title").text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Answer (score 2):

The SVG `<title>` element is not displayed on screen.  It is used as the tooltip text by browsers (and is also used by screen readers) in the same way as a title attribute in HTML.

I.e., the SVG code

```
<svg>
   <image xlink:href="image.png">
      <title>My PNG</title>
   </image>
</svg>
```

Is equivalent to the HTML code

```
<div>
   <img src="image.png" title="My PNG" />
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. what's the syntax to display persistent text instead of as a tooltip text.

Comment: You need to add an actual `<text>` element.  Here's an example with text labels next to the nodes: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

Answer (score 1):

Attribute `title` is supposed to be displayed as a tooltip (if you hover over a node), and it is really correctly displayed, check it out. (I know... it's not logical, but such is standard)

Comment: that's odd... because I'm not seeing the title even when i do a mouseover. i tried both Safari and Firefox.

Comment: 1 sec over a node was enough for my Firefox and Chrome to pop the tooltip.

Comment: In most browsers you have to hold the mouse still over the element, to keep tooltips from popping up here there and everywhere -- and for these little nodes, it has to be fairly precise.