# Appending text to D3 force layout graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, force-layout

I'm trying to modify the force layout graph here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045 by appending text within the circles, but the text doesn't appear. I added this block of code to the original code on the site.

```
node.append("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your code in entirety, but I think you are adding text INTO circles, and since circles are small, you don't see the text.

Now, your nodes are currently circles (I just suppose). If you want both circles and text for each node, your nodes should be svg g elements (g stands for "group"), and to each such g element you assign a circle and a text. More about that you can find [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/NIamAI9Yy60) (code is included there too)

EDIT: Once you see labels, you will like to position them in a nice way in relation to nodes. Here is an almost official recommendation related to positioning labels to the nodes of a graph:

For vertical alignment, use the "dy" attribute:

```
by default, the baseline of the text is at the origin (bottom-aligned)
a dy of .35em centers the text vertically
a dy of .72em places the topline of the text at the origin (top-aligned)
```

Using `em` units is nice because it will scale automatically based on the font size. If you don't specify units, it defaults to pixels.

For horizontal alignment, use the "text-anchor" attribute:

```
the default is "start" (left-aligned for left-to-right languages)
"middle"
"end"
```

Comment: Regardless of the size of the circles, you can't add a text element inside a circle.  When I linked to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) on your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081503/text-not-rendered-in-d3-visualization) I should have emphasized that it used group (`<g>`) elements as "nodes", and then added the circle and text elements separately to the group, instead of making the circles themselves the "nodes" as in the example you were working from.

Comment: P.S.  I should clarify, that if your circles are big enough you can still make it *look* like the text is inside the circle, by centering the text over the circle (use CSS `text{text-anchor:middle; alignment-baseline:middle;}` to get it centred on a point).  But as far as the browser is concerned, the circle and the text have to be sibling elements, not nested one inside the other.

Comment: Yes, and also I should say circles and texts can be generated separately, without g, but in that case data binding must be done twice, once for circles, and second time for texts. The approach with g is cleaner. For exercise, you can try both later on. And you can also try to add some image too, as third element of a node.